# Могу ли я задавать поинты для полилинии через css

Tags: html, css, svg, polyline

```css
polyline {
  points: 35, 35 40, 50 70, 50;
}
```

```html
<svg width='80px' height='80px'>
  <rect width='80' height='80' fill='none' rx='50' stroke='black'/>
  <polyline points="35,35 40,50 60,10" fill="none"  stroke="black" stroke-width='2'/>
</svg>
```

Никак не пойму, можно ли это сделать через `CSS` или нет всё-таки?

Comment: нет! http://prntscr.com/k017df

Comment: тут уже ответили https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51066433/can-i-specify-the-points-for-polyline-through-css